# Change date format for wine (Windows software)

Tags: wine, locale

When I run a windows software with wine1.6 on Ubuntu 14.04, it asks to change date format to dd/mm/yyyy.

[image]

Now what to do? How can I change format for this?

*This question is not about changing date/time format for showing in indicator.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open Terminal, run:

   ```
   wine regedit
   ```
2. Follow path:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International
   ```
3. Change the entry `sShortDate` to `dd/MM/yyyy` (notice the capital `M`)

   [image: screen]

Comment: Take a look also in sTimeFormat and sShortTime.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same difficulty and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/475422/109449) was of great help. The only thing is the regedit entry was reverting back to default each time I run the application. This was happening because I had to set `LANG=pt_BR.utf8` before calling `wine <myapp.exe>`.

So the solution for me was:

1. issued `export LANG=pt_BR.utf8`;
2. followed [user.dz's steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/475422/109449);
3. run `wine <myapp.exe>`

My application also demanded `arial.ttf` font, which I downloaded to `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts`.